# Simulating phonecalls, sms, alarm or music in background when testing with Android Espresso

Tags: android, mockito, dagger-2, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

I am testing an app which has a registration flow and I want to test if incoming calls, sms, alarms or other notifications during this flow will create problems. I am using Espresso for UI automation.

I am new at this and have searched quite a bit but don't seem to find a one shot solution to simulate these, I found telnet for calls but I am using a physical device and did not find anything for others.

If there is a framework for simulating these, please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @GhostCat I couldnt find one so I am asking if there exists one way, you can always obfuscate your straight reply with optional things, also I have seen quite a lot of opinionated and recommended answers here

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing more than one application, as it seems from your questions where you mention calls, sms, etc. which are assumed to be handled by other applications, you should use UiAutomator instead of Espresso.

You can find more information in [Testing UI for Multiple Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html)

In case you want to generate those tests automatically you can take a look at [culebra.dtmilano.com](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/).

Comment: Actually its a single application, these are various testcases where in i am registering and a call comes in(or a notification), my entered data should not get lost, I am testing this. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a simple or complex application, Espresso is restricted to one and you won't be able to go back from phone call or sms message received.

Answer (score 0):

So, as this is still unanswered and may help someone in future.

There is NO framework currently which can do these on a physical device, you can execute shell commands programatically  on an emulator for calls etc.

For me, I used a 3rd party app like automate on a different device and sent sms from my app to it and it inturn called me back, you can add most of the functionality required by this. If you dont want sms charges, you can use discover bluetooth and trigger calls when you see a particular device. Add relevant permissions to use these in your app.